# Write Avro records to HDFS using StreamingFileSink

Tags: apache-flink

What is the correct way to write avro records to HDFS directory using StreamingFileSink? 
The StreamingFileSink has a RowFormat method which can output one record at a time using provided Encoder which is not correct to create avro formatted files with schema.
There is AvroParquetWriter (using BulkWriter) which can convert avro records to Parquet.
What could be a similar way of creating avro files? What interfaces need to be implemented so that writing records is in sync with Flink’s checkpointing? Are there any implementations available which can be refered to create such avro files?